# Payflow - Can't get the result code of 12

Tags: .net, paypal, express-checkout

I am testing sandbox payflows for the code of 12. Based on the documentation (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#submit-credit-card-transactions) i should get it for the amount that im using, which is 1012$ using one of the cards present on that page instead im always getting result 0. Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong in that testing?

Here is my SetExpressCheckout request:

```
TRXTYPE[1]=S&EMAIL[0]=&PHONENUM[0]=&CUSTOM[36]=3d96670b-3bdd-4fa0-a0b2-0c64a452e44e&COUNTRYCODE[2]=US&LOCALECODE[2]=US&TENDER[1]=P&ACTION[1]=S&RETURNURL[26]=http://www.myreturnurl.com&CANCELURL[26]=http://www.mycancelurl.com&AMT[8]=1,012.00&CURRENCY[3]=USD&ORDERID[36]=3d96670b-3bdd-4fa0-a0b2-0c64a452e44e&SHIPTOSTATE[2]=NJ&SHIPTOCOUNTRY[2]=US&SHIPTOPHONE[0]=&SHIPTOEMAIL[0]=&SHIPTOFIRSTNAME[4]=MARY&SHIPTOLASTNAME[11]=[REMOVED]&USER[6]=Lukasz&VENDOR[6]=[removed]&PARTNER[6]=PayPal&PWD[9]=XXXXXXXXX
```

Here is my DoExpressCheckout request:

```
TRXTYPE[1]=S&LOCALECODE[2]=US&TENDER[1]=P&TOKEN[20]=EC-[REMOVED]&ACTION[1]=D&PAYERID[13]=[REMOVED]&AMT[8]=1,012.00&CURRENCY[3]=USD&USER[6]=Lukasz&VENDOR[6]=[REMOVED]&PARTNER[6]=PayPal&PWD[9]=XXXXXXXXX
```

I Removed sensitive info, but I am using the PayFlow .Net SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The testing parameters are for pure credit card transactions, not for Express Checkout which is why you are always seeing an approval.